# Xcode - Use of undeclared identifier after pod install

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've just updated my Pods and am getting this:

```
/Users/snowcrash/projects/test/AppDelegate.m:271:34: Use of undeclared identifier 'AFHTTPClient'
```

I assume it's not picking up my Pods but not sure why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have migrated from AFNetworking 1 to 2?

Comment: Thanks - just checked and AFHTTPClient is not supported in version 2.